# Hive regexp_replace failed to replace backslash

Tags: regex, hive, special-characters, backslash, regexp-replace

I have a table with a single column `name_string`, which contains backslash character. I wanted to remove the backslash character using `regexp_replace`, but it does not work.

Table:

```
create table t (name_string varchar(100));
insert into table t values ('\\"aaa\\"'), ('\\"bbb\\"');
```

Query:

```
select 
   name_string, regexp_replace(name_string, '\\"', '"')
from  t;
```

returning

```
+--------------+----------+
| name_string  |   _c1    |
+--------------+----------+
| \"aaa\"      | \"aaa\"  |
| \"bbb\"      | \"bbb\"  |
+--------------+----------+
```

However, `select regexp_replace('\"aaa\"', '\\"', '"')` returns the correct result.

I am confused about why this may be the case. Could someone please shed light on this? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Use 4 backslashes:

```
select regexp_replace(name_string,'\\\\"','"') from t;
```

Only backslash needs escaping. In Java and in regex the backslash has special meaning and needs escaping.

Comment: I wanted to replace a single slash to a double slash and I'm trying the below but it doesn't work as expected. Can you please help

create table test ( s1 string )
insert into test(s1) values ('/')
insert into test(s1) values ('ab')
insert into test(s1) values ('\\')
select s1, regexp_replace(s1, '//','\\\\\\\\\\\\\\') from test;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```sql
select 
   name_string, regexp_replace(name_string, '\\\"', '"')
from  t;
```

I think it's about escaping - you escape 2 characters- backslash and double quote